# How to create network bridge for KVM with nmcli?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, kvm-virtualization, fedora

I used to create a network bridge on CentOS 7 as seen below, where I would disable NetworkManager and edit the config files by hand.

However I would like to do it with `nmcli` and therefore use NetworkManager.

This article says it is done by

```
nmcli con add ifname br0 type bridge con-name br0
nmcli con add type bridge-slave ifname eno1 master br0
nmcli connection show
```

but doesn't explain why of a sudden a `bridge-slave` is introduced and what it is for.

**Question**

Can anyone explain what a `bridge-slave` is and if these 3 commands are indeed the way to create a network bridge for KVM?

```
cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
cp ifcfg-eno1 _ifcfg-eno1.backup

cat << EOF > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0
DEVICE=br0
TYPE=Bridge
IPADDR=xxx.xxx.xx.xx
PREFIX=22
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
DELAY=0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DNS1=xx.xxx.xx.x
DNS2=xx.xxx.xx.x
GATEWAY=x.xxx.xx.x
EOF

cat << EOF > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1
HWADDR=A0:D3:C1:05:C3:30
DEVICE=eno1
TYPE=Ethernet
NAME=eno1
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
BRIDGE=br0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
EOF

systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
systemctl disable NetworkManager.service

systemctl restart network
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A network bridge (in this case) is a virtual interface that joins one ore more network interfaces. It can be compared with a switch. If you add an interface, in this example eno1 (your physical network interface) to the bridge, it is called a slave of the bridge.

The idea is, to add the physical interface to the bridge (this is, what "nmcli con add type bridge-slave ifname eno1 master br0" does) and do the IP configuration on the bridge-interface instead of the phsyical interface.

If you now create a VM and connect it to your br0 interface, the VM's network adapter will be a slave of br0, too. So you have some kind of switched networking between the VM's network adapter and eno1.

Comment: Is there are a commands to see the members of the bridge? E.g. when install KVM on Fedora it creates `virbr0`, but I can't see anywhere that `en0` is part of the bridge.

Comment: @Sanda `bridge`, `brctl`, `ip` and I'm sure many others.